# Why UPS for sensitive SMD development?

Tags: power-supply, safety, surface-mount, ups

My friend suggests me UPS for SMD development. I already have a a surge protector over all devices. He recommended the UPS that transmit all energy through its battery and he recommend to find some silent UPS: some UPSs have a spinning coil or something like that.

**Why UPS?**

- Power continuity. -No, not the main reason.
- *"Line conditioning"*? More [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9292457#9292457).

Comment: SMD development? What do surface mount devices have to do with a UPS? Is this for your soldering iron or something?

Comment: You don't need a UPS for any of that.  No OS to go down, no data to use.

Comment: A surge supressor and a UPS are two very different things

Comment: It is difficult to tell what is being asked here.

Comment: @MattYoung why? A guy is recommending me to get UPS and I am trying to find out why. The chat attributes the thing for "line conditioning" that I cannot understand.

Comment: What SMD development? (And I'm also assuming that means surface mount devices...) Design? Testing? Assembly? Without context this question is gibberish.

Comment: I do not think you should take electronics advice from this friend.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you need any special kind of UPS, unless you have particularly power sensitive equipment. Nearly any modern switching power supply will handle the transition from mains power to battery of a typical line interactive UPS. This type of UPS will protect you from both power surges and power sags, switching to battery when the mains voltage is out of range.

More expensive UPS's  (like the APC Smart-UPS series) will have a better sine-wave output versus the stepped sine-wave cheaper UPS's have (like the APC Back-UPS series) which [can cause problems with particularly sensitive equipment](http://www.minutemanups.com/support/pwr_un10.php).  Even cheaper UPS's have a square wave output, which you should probably avoid since it can be hard on power supplies.

If you really want a UPS that always filters the input power, look for an online UPS (like the APC Smart-UPS Online series). This type of UPS will convert AC to DC to charger the batteries and power the inverter to create AC output. However, unless you have particularly bad mains power (like if you're powered from a small generator or have large industrial loads creating noise or power sags), this is overkill in most situations.

Most UPS's will be completely silent in normal operation, only running the fan when running on battery power or while charging the batteries. However, an online UPS under heavy load may run the fan continuously.

I'm not sure what the "spinning coil" UPS you're referring to is. There is a [Ferroresonant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninterruptible_power_supply#Ferro-resonant) type of UPS that uses a special type of transformer that uses the magnetic field of the transformer to ensure a smoother cutover from mains power to UPS power (and the transformer can help filter the power).

Or maybe you're referring to a [motor-generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninterruptible_power_supply#Rotary) UPS that uses a spinning motor to drive a generator that powers your loads. The mechanical energy in the flywheel stores energy that eases the transition from mains power to battery and/or diesel power. I think this type of UPS is only used for large loads.

(I used APC equipment as examples only because I'm most familiar with their product line)

Comment: +1 An excellent system-level summary of UPS architecture.